# On the $r=2$ case of Hartshorne Ex II.6.5c

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In this question, we are asked to find the divisor class group $\operatorname{Cl} Q$ of $$Q=\operatorname{Proj} k[x_0,\dots,x_n]/(x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2).$$

Some known information:

- Let $X=C(Q)$, the cone of $Q$ in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$, $\operatorname{Cl} X\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$.
- We have the exact sequence $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\operatorname{Cl} Q\to\operatorname{Cl} X=\mathbb{Z}/2\to 0$, where the first map is given by $1\mapsto Q.H$, where $H$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$ (Ex. II.6.3c).

My question is: How can we tell $\operatorname{Cl} Q=\mathbb{Z}$, but not $\operatorname{Cl} Q=\mathbb{Z}\oplus T_2$ for some 2-torsion $T_2$?

I had seen a couple of solutions online but none of them gave a satisfactory argument to me.

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: By the way, if you use `$\operatorname{Cl}$` to format $\operatorname{Cl}$ (and similarly with other things that don't have predetermined commands), you don't have to fiddle with the extra space inside the brackets. I've made the formatting upgrade for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change of coordinates referred to in (b) to write $Q=\operatorname{Proj} k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]/(x_0x_1-x_2^2)$. The map $\Bbb Z\to \operatorname{Cl} Q$ is given by $1\mapsto Q.H$, so let $H=V(x_2)\subset\Bbb P^n$ and observe that $Q.H$ is the union of the two linear divisors $V(x_0,x_2)$ and $V(x_1,x_2)$ each appearing with coefficient 1. These are linearly equivalent divisors as witnessed by the rational function $\frac{x_0}{x_1}$, so the map $\Bbb Z\to \operatorname{Cl} Q$ takes the form $1\mapsto 2D$ for some $D\in\operatorname{Cl} Q$. Therefore tensoring with $\Bbb Z/2$, our exact sequence becomes $$\Bbb Z/2\stackrel{0}{\to} \operatorname{Cl} Q \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb Z/2\to \Bbb Z/2\to 0.$$ Thus $\operatorname{Cl} Q$ must be $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Why would one think of doing this? The difference between the two possble exact sequences $0\to\mathbb Z\to E\to\mathbb Z/2\to0$ is that ine one the image of $1$ is twice something, while in the other it isn't.